# Insert new rows based on conditions - Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table:

table1

```
unique_id       col_id      col_nm      col_val     sequ 
1               1           testq 1     100         1   
1               2           testc 1     abc         1   
1               1           testq 1     101         2   
1               2           testc 1     xyz         2
1               5           test 5      10          1       
1               8           test 6      100         1   


2               1           testq 1     100         1   
2               2           testc 1     pqr         1   
2               1           testq 1     101         2   
2               2           testc 1     xxy         2
2               5           test 5      qqw         1       
2               8           test 6      100         1
```

I need to insert new rows in the table based on the following condition:

1. Find `unique_id` and `sequ` of `col_id` = 1 and `col_nm` = 'testq 1' and `col_val` = 100
2. Find `col_val` of `col_id` = 2 and `col_nm` = 'testc 1' and `sequ` = {`sequ` of step 1} and unique_id = {`unique_id` of step 1}.
3. Insert a new row for the corresponding `unique_id`, with col_id = 100, col_nm = 'test q100c', `col_val` = {col_val found in step 2}, `sequ` = {sequ found in step 2}

The output would be:

```
unique_id       col_id      col_nm      col_val     sequ 
1               1           testq 1     100         1   
1               2           testc 1     abc         1   
1               1           testq 1     101         2   
1               2           testc 1     xyz         2
1               5           test 5      10          1       
1               8           test 6      100         1   
1               100         test q100c  abc         1

2               1           testq 1     100         2   
2               2           testc 1     pqr         2   
2               1           testq 1     101         2   
2               2           testc 1     xxy         2
2               5           test 5      qqw         1       
2               8           test 6      100         1   
2               100         test q100c  pqr         2
```

Is there anyway in SQL to achieve this?

Comment: `unique_id` - lol

Comment: Yeah, not the best convention :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use WITH clause in an INSERT … SELECT construct. So something like this?

```
insert into table1
with s1 as (
  select t.unique_id 
         , t.sequ 
  from table1 t
  where t.col_id = 1 
  and t.col_nm = 'testq 1' 
  and t.col_val = 100 )
  , s2 as (
     select s1.*
            , t.col_val
      from s1
           join table1 t 
              on t.sequ = s1.sequ
              and t.unique_id = s1.unique_id
  where t.col_id = 2
  and t.col_nm = 'testc 1' 
)
select s2.unique_id
       ,100 as col_id 
       ,'test q100c' as col_nm
       ,s2.col_val
       ,s2.sequ 
from s2
/
```

I'm not sure I have entirely understood your rules - I used the `col_val` from step #2 (which is what your expected output shows) rather than the value from step #1 as your rule 3 states - but I hope this gives you a start. Also, this may not be a very efficient approach. I offer no guarantees regarding performance over a large volume of data.

Comment: Actually step 3 takes output from step 2. Is there a way to improve performance? I have a table with over 50 million rows and would like it to be efficient.

Comment: Is there a way to use merge query to do this? Would that be faster?

Comment: It's impossible to give tuning advice on such scant detail. It may be that this query performs well enough. Try it. But if you want it to go faster you'll need to provide much more information. Please read [this helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34975420/146325) which explains how to ask Oracle optimization questions.